# ITEXT 7 (Java) - Rendering Cells in reverse direction (Right to Left)

Tags: java, itext, itext7

I am using ITEXT 7 for generating a table with 2 colums and I want to know if it is possible to reverse the direction of cell creation in a row?

Each cell would have a width of half the width of the page. The 1st cell to be generated should be generated on the right half of the page, 2nd cell would be generated on the left, 3rd cell would be generated in the next row on the right and so on..

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible at the moment with iText7.
The default (and in fact only) method for adding content to a `Table` object assumes you wish to add top to bottom, left to right.

What often helps is to define a pseudo table object that does offer these convenience methods.

You could simply cache an entire row, and upon completion add it to the underlying table in reverse order.

Other benefits include:

- option to add text immediately
- option to add an array of String and have it represent a row
- option to access random cells by row/column index (if you implement the intermediate datastructure as a Map or String[][] or IElement[][])

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what you mean by a Pseudo Table here?
Also for reference, I am using this for creating empty form fields using cell renderers for later adding digital signatures.

Comment: By PseudoTable I mean: a datastructure that holds the IElement objects you would normally add to Table, and acts as a wrapper (or factory) of Table. On this PseudoTable you could define the aforementioned methods.